If spreadsheet ID is not equal to and number of rows less than?
Is it possible to create the following logic using Google Script:
(if spreadsheet id is not equal to <id> and number of rows filled on sheet <name> < 100) {
  runFunction()
}
else {
  return dialog window to the user with <text>
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skills. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About number of rows on sheet <name> < 100, in this case, which Spreadsheet do you want to use spreadsheet id or <id>? And, from return dialog window to the user with <text>, your Google Apps Script project is required to be the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about your current situation? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

As an additional question, about number of rows on sheet <name>, in this case, which do you want to check the maximum number of rows in the sheet or the last row of the data range in the sheet?

Thank you! id of the spreadsheet that is associated with the script. So yes, the dialog window should be prompted inside the spreadsheet that is associated with the script. Concerning number of rows, it should be number of rows filled on sheet , apologies!

I'm writing this from memory on my phone but it should be something like this:
(if SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getID() !== id && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name).getLastRow() < 100) {
  runFunction();
}
else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(text);
}

